# Notebook Principal Branch not working yet

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex, compatibility

This notebook again is useful to see in a 3D plot of the complex log function :

- the principal branch
- the branches

For this purpose, I downloaded the notebook from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComplexAnalysis/PrincipalBranch.nb.

I also downloaded the `` Utilities`Typesetting` `` package of Eric Weisstein
First, it goes wrong to see the "branches" in a 3D plot and then it goes wrong with the "principal(branch)" 3D plot.
I start with the branches calculation.

```
<< Utilities`Typesetting`

branches = 
 Show[Graphics3D[
                 ParametricPlot3D[
                                 Evaluate[
 Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], 
 Im[Log[r Exp[I θ]]] + 2 Pi k}, {k, -1, 1}]], {r, .01, 
 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
 DisplayFunction -> Identity,
 PlotPoints -> {4, 25}][[1]] /. 
 Polygon[x_] :> 
 If[Max[z = Last /@ x] - Min[z] > .5, 
 Polygon[Join[# - {0, 0, 2 Pi} & /@ Take[x, 2], Take[x, -2]]], 
 Polygon[x]]],
 Axes -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x, y, HoldForm[Im[Log[z]]]},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotLabel -> 
 StyleForm["multiple branches", FontSlant -> "Italic", 
 FontFamily -> "Times"],
 PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

Note: don't know yet how to write the code here in a programmer style

Comment: Does `Normal@ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[
    Table[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], 
      Im[Log[r Exp[I \[Theta]]]] + 2 Pi k}, {k, -1, 1}]], {r, .01, 
    1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
   PlotPoints -> {4, 25}] /. 
 Polygon[x_] :> 
  If[Max[z = Last /@ x] - Min[z] > .5, 
   Polygon[Join[# - {0, 0, 2 Pi} & /@ Take[x, 2], Take[x, -2]]], 
   Polygon[x]]` help? Nothing in your code relies on non-System` functions. `GraphicsComplex` was introduced in V6 and plotters were changed to use it.

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks, yes its a spiral 
The sentence : Nothing in your code relies on non-System` functions. ?, Please clarify this .

Comment: Look up Context and related tutorials. Your question points to a different context than System but your code does not use it

Comment: @ Michael E2 , i am sorry but i am lost here

Comment: Read this, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#27982, and the sections following it, or read the whole thing. I don't know where to begin explaining except to repeat what's in the docs. You will need to spend a little time learning about such things if you want to understand what depends on a package and what does not.

Comment: Does not yet go smoothly to find the right information in MMA
Must do even better
To find out everything about a package for example.
That link you gave is good to use

Comment: A line starts with 4 spaces will be formated as code block. Check this for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5):

That's old, unnecessarilly-complex code.  Start with:
$$
\begin{align}
\log(z)&=\ln|z|+i\arg(z) \\
&=\ln|z|+i\left[\text{Arg}(z)+2 k\pi\right];\quad -\pi\lt\text{Arg}(z)\leq \pi
\end{align}
$$
$\ln|z|$ is the single-valued real component but $\arg(z)$ is the multivalued imaginary component.  $k=0$ is the principal branch of the imgainary component.  Simpler code to plot branching $k=0,1,2$:

```
f[z_, k_] = Log[Abs[z]] + I (Arg[z] + 2 k Pi)
realPlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Re[z], Im[z], Re[f[z, 0]]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r,
     0.001, 1}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Style["Real Sheet", 16]];
colors = {Red, Blue, Green};
imagPlotList = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[{Re[z], Im[z], Im[f[z, i - 1]]} /. 
     z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 0.001, 1}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]],
   {i, 1, 3}
   ];
imagPlot = 
  Show[imagPlotList, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Imag sheets", 16]];
GraphicsRow[{realPlot, imagPlot}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks your code  ,looks simpler in function notation ,then the original code from Eric Weisstein.
Do have also a notebook "Riemann Surface" from Eric Weisstein, but there are the surfaces not so easy to define as a function.

Comment: It is a simple one this boxplot 
Points of improvement can be 
-naming the axes
-be able to rotate 
- indicate the distance between the branches
- maybe interactive ?
Interesting is also the functionality of geogebra program to experiment in Complex analysis
Can this also be done in MMA? 

See: https://complex-analysis.com/

https://www.geogebra.org/m/rsqxtq9t ( interesting)

Comment: Oops.. i found rotate finally : doubleclick

Comment: @janhardo:  I looked at RiemannSurface.nb.  Eric is using an obsolete 3D viewer before Mathematica included a built-in interactive 3D viewer called LiveGraphics3D.  In RiemannSurface.nb, remove the line << Utilities`LiveGraphics3D` and then remove the WriteLiveForm construct around all the plot routines.  For example, for the first example in the notebook, after executing the first two commands, execute:   ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{r, i, v}], {u, -6, 2}, {v, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> {18, 32},
 Ticks -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}]

Comment: Also, just noticed his second example in RiemannSurface.nb is not working.  Again, it's unnecessarilly-complex and general code.  There are easier ways to generate specific Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Eric's code includes a replacement `/. Polygon[x_] :> …` because there's no `Exclusions` option in *v5.2*. Nowadays the code can be simplified to

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], Im[Log[r Exp[I θ]]] + 2 Pi k}, {k, -1, 1}], 
                {r, .01, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], Im[Log[r Exp[I θ]]]}, 
                 {r, .01, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
                 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
                 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For comparison, The followings are outputs in *v5.2*:

[image]

[image]

Just for fun, the following is a "quick" fix based on the logic of Eric's code, notice I've forced `Exclusions` to be `None`:

```
branches = Show[
  Graphics3D[Normal@
      ParametricPlot3D[
        Evaluate[Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], 
           Im[Log[r Exp[I θ]]] + 2 Pi k}, {k, -1, 1}]], {r, .01, 1}, {θ, 0,
          2 π}, PlotPoints -> {4, 25}, Exclusions -> None][[1]] /. 
     Line[pts_] :> Line[Split[pts, Abs@Last[#2 - #1] < Pi &]] /. 
    Polygon[x_, opt__] :> 
     If[Max[z = Last /@ x] - Min[z] > 
       Pi, {Polygon[Join[# - {0, 0, 2 Pi} & /@ Take[x, 2], Take[x, -2]], opt]}, {Polygon[
        x, opt]}]], Axes -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x, y, HoldForm[Im[Log[z]]]}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   StyleForm["multiple branches", FontSlant -> "Italic", FontFamily -> "Times"], 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

A new replacement `/. Line[pts_] :> Line[Split[pts, Abs@Last[#2 - #1] < Pi &]]` is added because `Mesh` option seems to be working in a different manner nowadays. (Not 100% sure what's the difference though. )