# How do I keep track of the discontinuous jumps of the argument of a complex function along a contour in the complex plane in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

In complex analysis,  let's say I choose a branch of the  complex logarithm (so that I can calculate the argument of a complex function),  and I want to study numerically the variation of the argument of this complex function along a given contour in the complex plane. I am not just interested in the principal argument,  I want to keep track of the discontinuous jumps of the argument of the complex function  along that given contour, when the function touches the branch cut. How do I do that in Mathematica?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Would be helpful if you precisely define an example $\log(z)$  branch $y(z)$, then an example paramaterization such as $z(t)$ over which you wish to evaluate $y(z(t))$.   Also essential you understand clearly the analytic geometry of the $\log(z)$.  Maybe this thread would be helpful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263861/notebook-principal-branch-not-working-yet/263867#263867

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMA will always give you the main branch. If you want a continuous function, you have to adjust the argument "by hand".

Here is a simple example:

```
fun[t_] = Exp[I t];
old = 0;
arg = 0;
Manipulate[
 arg = Arg[fun[t]];
 If[old - arg > Pi, arg += 2 Pi]; If[old - arg < -Pi, arg -= 2 Pi]; 
 old = arg;
 old = arg;
 Graphics[{
   {Green, Circle[]}
   , {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[ReIm[fun[t]]]}
   , Text[StringForm["Argument: ``", arg], {0, 1.1}, 
    BaseStyle -> Medium]
   }, Axes -> True]
 , {{t, 0}, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, TrackedSymbols :> t]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer @DanielHuber  . I assume this is just a fragment of the program.  It doesn't include the curve parametrization z(t), for which  we calculate arg f(z(t)) for a sequence of  close points along the curve, right?

Comment: This is only a demo to show how to keep track of a jump in the argument. You can look at it as a parametrized curve that is the circle and the function f would be the identity. Or you can look at it as: curve = straight line from -3Pi to 3Pi along the real axis and the function is Exp[I t]

Answer (score 1):

For the example you give, `Log`, its derivative is uniquely defined.  You can therefore specify the value by the integral along a defined path.  E.g.

```
path = Table[Exp[I n], {n, 1, 20}]
(* {E^I, E^(2 I), E^(3 I), E^(4 I), E^(5 I), E^(6 I), E^(
 7 I), E^(8 I), E^(9 I), E^(10 I), E^(11 I), E^(12 I), E^(13 I), E^(
 14 I), E^(15 I), E^(16 I), E^(17 I), E^(18 I), E^(19 I), E^(20 I)} *)

Integrate[1/x, Prepend[path, x]]
(* 19 I *)
```

(I don't know why Mathematica is quite so slow in evaluating this integral)